# How to import python libraries every time Jupyter interactive window starts in VS Code

Tags: jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

Whenever I start the Jupyter Interactive window in VS Code (using, ctrl+shift+p), I have to load several libraries that I use like numpy and pandas. Is there any way in which a selected set of libraries could be made to auto import every time the Jupyter Interactive window starts

something like

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

every time a new interactive window starts